# Is there a way to have a bank confirm that a deposit is no longer reversible?

Tags: united-states, scams

A lot of the [scams] questions involve a reversible deposit followed by a non-reversible withdrawal.

A common method is a bouncing check that can take over a month to bounce.

As the recipient of a deposit that might be invalid, is there a way to request that you back confirm or certify the deposit? Alternatively, can you ask them to ringfence the funds until they are confirmed?

This is a hypothetical situation for me, but it seems there are others who might benefit from knowing whether this is possible.

Comment: It is very dependent upon the bank.

Comment: Don't accept payments by reversible methods.  Particularly from strangers on the internet.

Comment: Unfortunately, the US is stuck in the financial dark ages and a baffling number of people still pay for things with checks.